# Is there anyway to retrieve OneNote page InkNode content from Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

I can get at the content of a OneNote notebook but I can't get the InkNode content from the page. The returned HTML from the page content has a HTML comment indicating that InkNode is not supported.

Any idea when this will be implemented?

Answer (score 5):

This is supported in microsoft-graph using the following format.

```
../pages/[pageid]/content?includeinkML=true
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as of late 2021, it doesn't seem to be working anymore.

Comment: Just checked it out. Not working in the graph explorer but working OK via rest API call. Might be worth filing a bug report with Microsoft

Comment: The query succeeds, but returns xml that doesn't include any inkml nodes (the note in question is all handwritten text)

Comment: I'm still able to retrieve inkml xml data with onenote and microsoftgraph APIs on my Sharepoint site. Graph explorer, however, returns an empty array when includeinkML=true is added to the page content request